# Узнать url изображения и добавить его в стили

Tags: jquery

Есть код:

$(document).ready(function(){
$("img").wrap("");
});

Надо его улучшить. Нужно взять значение src у картинки и поменстить его в бекграунд дива super-fon. какие команды для этого есть в jquery?

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводится к решению задач за автора. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var bgSrc = $('img').attr('src');
$('.super-fon').css('background-image', bgSrc);
```